# find the hidden rows and columns in the entire sheets of excel files using applescript

Tags: excel, applescript

I have tried to find the hidden rows and columns of entire sheets in the excel file using applescript, but it works for active sheet in the excel file and not for entire sheet. could you anyone help me to resolve this. Please find the code below

tell application "Microsoft Excel"

```
repeat with i from (count of worksheets) to 1 by -1
    set theSheet to name of sheet i of active workbook
    tell (get used range of sheet i of active workbook)
        repeat with j from 1 to count rows
            if hidden of row j of used range of sheet i then
                display dialog (theSheet & " " & "row " & j & " is hidden")
            end if
        end repeat
        repeat with k from 1 to count columns
            if hidden of column k of used range of sheet i then
                display dialog (theSheet & " " & "column " & k & " is hidden")
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end repeat
```

end tell

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
use scripting additions
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    set shAll to worksheets of active workbook
    
    repeat with ss in shAll -- loop sheets
        activate object ss
        set nSht to name of ss
        
        set cc to columns of used range of ss
        repeat with c in cc -- loop columns
            if hidden of c is true then
                set fci to first column index of c
                display dialog "Column " & (fci as text) & " of " & nSht with title "Hidden columns"
            end if
        end repeat -- of columns
        
        set rr to rows of used range of ss
        repeat with r in rr -- loop rows
            if hidden of r is true then
                set fri to first row index of r
                display dialog "Row " & (fri as text) & " of " & nSht with title "Hidden rows"
            end if
        end repeat -- of rows
        
    end repeat -- of sheets
end tell
```

I don't think that you can get hidden from sheets without first activating them. This is done with `activate object`.

NB `first column index` (and row) return the index for the matching row (variables 'fci'/'fri') so if you wanted to, you could collect those numbers in a list and then consolidate your display dialog commands. This might be useful depending upon how many hidden ranges you have.